# Do indexes work in NOT IN or <> clause?

Tags: sql, database, performance, indexing

I have read that normal indexes in (atleast Oracle) database are basically B- tree structures, and hence store the records treating appropriate root nodes. Records 'lesser than' the root are iteratively stored in the left portion of the tree, while records 'greater than' the root are stored to the right portion. It is this storage approach that helps in a faster scan, through tree traversal since depth and breadth is reduced.

However,while creating indexes or for performance tuning of a `where` clause, most guides speak about first prioritize the columns where equality is to be considered `(IN or = clause)` and then alone move to the columns with inequality clauses. `(NOT IN, <>)`. What is the cause of this advise? Should it not be feasible to predict that a given value does not exist as easily as it is to predict a given value exists, using tree traversal?

Do indexes not work with negation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is locality within the index.  If you have two columns with letters in col1 and numbers in col 2, then an index might look like:

```
Ind  col1 col2
 1    A    1
 2    A    1
 3    A    1
 4    A    2
 5    B    1
 6    B    1
 7    B    2
 8    B    3
 9    B    3
10    C    2
11    C    3
```

(`ind` is the position in the index.  The record locator is left out.)

If you are looking for `col1 = 'B'`, then you can find position 5 and then scan the index until position 9.  If you are looking for `col1 <> 'B'`, then you need to find the first record that is not `'B'` scan and repeat for the first record after.  This becomes worse with `IN` and `NOT IN`.

An additional factor is that if a relative handful of records satisfy the equality condition, then almost all records will fail -- and often indexes are not useful when almost all records need to be read.  One sometimes-exception to this are clustered indexes.

Oracle has better index optimizations than most databases -- it will do multiple scans starting in different locations.  Even so, an inequality is often much less useful for an index.