# What is the best type of index for non-selective column?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

Supposing I have a table:

```
create table MyTable
(
  column1 varchar(150),
  column2 ...,
  column3 ...,
  ...
)
```

Column1 contains 40% of null records, 10% of empty (`''`) values, and the rest is some meaningful values.
I have a number of queries which work only with non-empty records:

```
select ...
from MyTable
join TableA ...
join TableB ...
...
where column1 is not null and column1 <> ''
```

But **there are no** queries that filter dataset by meaningful value of column1:

```
select column2
from MyTable
where column1 = 'abcde'  -- NOT COMMON
```

It seems to be a good idea to half considered number of rows by introducing index on column1. I tried to use simple nonclustered index and filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_column1
    ON dbo.MyTable(column1)
    WHERE column1 is not null and column1 <> ''
```

but optimizer does not want to use it and I don't get any benefit in execution time.

Can I fasten such queries and what would be the most appropriate index type?

**Update:**

Actually index is used in simple queries with only table and exact indexed predicate, but if I add extra predicate, e.g. *column2 in (4, 7, 9)* it performs clustered index scan. The same with complex multi-join queries.

Comment: Make sure that the `WHERE` filter in the query matches closely the `WHERE` filter in the index. Optimizer should be able to use such index. See also http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2015/02/22/why-isn-t-my-filtered-index-being-used.aspx In essence, try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query.

Comment: Yes, predicate matches exactly, the only difference is aliases before column1.

Comment: No index - because 50% of records satisfy your condition. That's why optimizer ignores this index - it does not help with anything. And, as you have demonstrated, you refer other columns of this table in select, so this index is not a _covering_ one.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/optimizer-limitations-with-filtered-indexes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897198/filtered-index-condition-is-ignored-by-optimizer In non-trivial query it may be tricky to persuade optimizer to generate optimal plan. I'd start with the simplest possible query, check that it uses index as intended and then add more joins to it and watch at which point the plan changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on selectivity of indexes.

[Do indexes work in NOT IN or <> clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756118/do-indexes-work-in-not-in-or-clause)

Comment: where did you get the idea that  null values cannot be indexed?

Comment: @MartinSmith, maybe I have not grasped it fully. But..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175591/index-for-nullable-column. And http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/null/index

Comment: They are both about Oracle. SQL Server indexes nulls same as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the column1 of MyTable has half amount of values that are not NULL and not empty string. So if you created index on column1 with filter `WHERE column1 is not null and column1 <> ''`  , AND the execution plan DOES use that index, index seek should be used.

If index seed did not used, then we need to check the estimated rows and actual rows, if they are different by a lot rows, then the stats need to be updated.

For your first query:
    select ...
    from MyTable
    join TableA ...
    join TableB ...
    ...
    where column1 is not null and column1 <> ''

Most situation the execution plan would use index scan.